# angularjs - Accessing ui-bootstrap modal dismiss and close function from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have service for modal invoking as shown.

```
.service('modalService', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

        var modalDefaults = {
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: true,
            modalFade: true
        };

        this.showModal = function (template) {

            modalDefaults.template = template;

            modalDefaults.controller = 'modalController';
            return $modal.open(modalDefaults).result;
        };

    }])

.controller('modalController', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        console.log('modalController');
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close('okResult');
        };
        $scope.cancel = function (result) {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    })
```

I invoke this modal from a controller say 'controllerA'.
The template used for modal contains custom drectives.
I need to get the modal controller functionalities like $modalInstance.dismiss and $modalInstance.close in the controller of the custom directive controller of the template, say 'controllerB'.

My template is like this:

```
<custom-form></custom-form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to call method of another controller

**1 Sharing controller**

we can share controller's method using `$controller` in app.controller

**2.Sharing rootScope**

share $rootScope both controller using `$rootScope`