# ui-bootstrap: accessing modal instance from within directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Noob alert!

The question here is exactly the one that I have: [angularjs - Accessing ui-bootstrap modal dismiss and close function from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972363/angularjs-accessing-ui-bootstrap-modal-dismiss-and-close-function-from-another)

However, I don't understand the answer that was chosen as correct!  I understand the words but don't understand how to share the controller.

I have an app controller that opens a modal, and within the modal's template, I have a directive.  I would like to be able manipulate the modal instance from within the directive's controller.

Here's my markup:

```
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="settingsModal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm update!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <calendar-settings cid="calendarId"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <!-- I want these buttons inside the directive instead -->
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>
```

In the body of the modal, I am calling the calendarSettings directive, and I'd like to be able to use the .dismiss and .close methods of the modal instance from within my directive.

Here's what the open method looks like:

```
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'settingsModal',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceController',
                resolve: {
                    item: function() {
                        return $scope.sEntry;
                    },
                    cid: function() {
                        return id;
                    }
                },
                reject: {
                    item: function() {
                        return $scope.sEntry;
                    },
                    cid: function() { return null; }
                }
            });
```

And here's the ModalInstanceController:

```
    calendarsApp.controller('ModalInstanceController', function($scope, $modalInstance, item, cid){
        $scope.item = item;
        $scope.calendarId = cid;
        console.log(item);

        $scope.ok = function () {
          $modalInstance.close($scope.item);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

I think what I want to do is easy, but I'm not sure how to expose the modal instance controller to the directive, or if there is a different approach I should be thinking about.

NOTE: I didn't paste the code from the directive in here.  But I'm trying to access the close and dismiss methods of the modal instance from within my directive's controller.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
So 

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'settingsModal',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceController',
                    resolve: {
                        item: function() {
                            return $scope.sEntry;
                        },
                        cid: function() {
                            return id;
                        }
                    },
                    reject: {
                        item: function() {
                            return $scope.sEntry;
                        },
                        cid: function() { return null; }
                    }

                 //This comes from ModalInstanceController result is                 
                  //equivalent to whatever u send back 
                }).result.then(function(result){
        console.log(result); //Press f12 on chrome and go to console.
    });



 calendarsApp.controller('ModalInstanceController', function($scope, $modalInstance, item, cid){
        $scope.item = item;
        $scope.calendarId = cid;
        console.log(item);

        $scope.ok = function () {
            //You are sending back $scope.item but if you want everything 

//send back the $scope which is equivalent to  sending back //ModalInstanceController
         // $modalInstance.close($scope.item);
          $modalInstance.close($scope);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

Comment: Also... use typescript instead of plain JS. This will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I think I understand what you said, but I still don't think I understand how to access these things from within a directive's controller.  I didn't put the directive's code into the question, but there is a directive called calendarSettings with its own isolate scope, where I'm trying to access the modal Instance from, and call the close or dismiss methods from the directive's controller